# Mat-card doesn't grow after media size change

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I'm building an small angular app with Flex-layout and I got stuck.

On big screen all works correctly, but when for small devices I want to each property occupied one row. So I set property fxFlex.lt-sm=100 for each row. Please find bellow screen shots and my code. Maybe one of you could give me hint where I made mistake?

![1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMGvG.png "ok"
![2]https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3yxG.png "wrong"

I set property fxFlex.lt-sm=100 for each row. Please find bellow screen shots and my code. Maybe one of you could give me hint where I made mistake?

```js
<mat-card>
  <mat-list role="list">
    <mat-list-item
      role="listitem"
      *ngFor="let user of (usersState | async).users"
      class="users-list">
      <div
        fxFill
        fxLayout="row wrap"
        fxLayoutGap="5px">
        <div
          fxFlex="30"
          fxFlex.lt-sm="100">
          <p>{{ user.email }}</p>
        </div>
        <div
          fxFlex="20"
          fxFlex.lt-sm="100">
          <p>{{ user.username }}</p>
        </div>
        <div
          fxFlex="20"
          fxFlex.lt-sm="100">
          <p>{{ user.active ? 'Account active' : 'Account inactive'}}</p>
        </div>
        <div
          fxFlex.lt-sm="100">
          <p>actions</p>
        </div>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      </div>
    </mat-list-item>
  </mat-list>
</mat-card>
```

Also mat-card doesn't adjust to the actual size of content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code works as expected. however, `mat-list-item` has a fixed `height` of `48px`. that's why in small screens `mat-list-item` height doesn't grow as you expect. also, `mat-card` doesn't adjust to the actual size of content as well.

overriding `height` on `mat-list-item` as follows should solve both problems.

```
.users-list {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

here is a working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rgepcp

Comment: Thank You for quick answer! You are my hero! :-)